# Repository for com.tridion libs 7.1.0

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

I can't resolve the following dependencies for a project using the DXA java version. I checked the repo1.maven and they are not there.

- com.tridion:cd_odata:jar:7.1.0
- com.tridion:cd_odata_types:jar:7.1.0
- com.tridion:cd_preview_ambient:jar:7.1.0
- com.tridion:cd_preview_web:jar:7.1.0:

In fact, checking http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tridion/ I realised that the names of the jars are totally different. Are those in the repo maven only for sdl web 8? may I install the other jars into my repo? Is there any clear documentation about libs intallation for developers? I'm finding out a lot of failing dependencies.

Comment: The 7.1 jars are not available in Maven central (only Web 8 jars are available there), you need to have those available in your own local maven repository. Did you follow the online documentation? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-2DCA4816-76E9-45FE-BE9E-298D3E6D1ACE

Comment: @BartKoopman, you should move this comment to an answer, as it is the correct answer to the question being asked.

Comment: Can you let us know if this answered your question?

Comment: Yes! it solved our problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bart Koopman said, artifacts for 7.1.0 are not in Maven Central. To be able to use them, you should either manually install them into your Maven repository or configure your project to use local project artifactory.

Example can be found 
on https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/master/dxa-example-webapp/pom.xml in `<repositories/>` tag, and uses https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/master/local-project-repo